# Adding an empty array to hash

Tags: perl, data-structures, perl-data-structures

What is the difference between:

```
my %x;
push @{$x{'12'}}, ();
```

and:

```
my %y;
$y{'12'} = ();
```

Why does the following work for `x` and not for `y`?

```
my @x1 = @{$x{'12'}}; #legal
my @y1 = @{$y{'12'}}; #illegal
```

Comment: This is a good question. It's a reminder that `perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; my %y ; $y{'12'} = (); $y{'13'} = []; ;  $y{'14'} = undef ; $y{'15'} = "";print Dumper \%y;'` can be educational/instructive.

Comment: Rather than `-e use...` you can just use `-M`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$y{'12'} = ();
```

and

```
@{$y{'12'}} = ();
```

are not the same. In the first case, you are assigning to a hash element. In the second case, you are assigning to the array referenced by that hash element.

Except it doesn't contain a reference to an array, so Perl creates one for you through a feature called "autovivification". In other words,

```
@{$y{'12'}} = ();
```

is equivalent to

```
@{ $y{'12'} //= [] } = ();
```

where `[]` creates an array and returns a reference to it. Given that `$y{'12'}` is non-existent and thus undefined, the above simplifies to the following:

```
$y{'12'} = [];
```

Comment: What is going to happen to auto-vivification?  In newer perls with `defined/or` two statements `$hash{'whatever2'} //= [] ; push $hash{'whatever2'} , "stuff" ;` seemed more readable to me months after writing it than using `push @{ $hash{'whatever2'} } ,  "stuff" ;`. But ... `push on reference is experimental ...`.

Comment: [Effective Perler article on auto-vivification](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification/).

Comment: @G. Cito, Re "What is going to happen to auto-vivification?", No changes planned or even suggested. /// I think `push $hash{'whatever2'} , "stuff"` is already gone.

Comment: Oh there is `use experimental 'postderef';` and `push $hash{'whatever'}->@* ,  "stuff" ;`

Comment: @G. Cito, Yup, and that's no longer experiemental in 5.24

Comment: @G. Cito, By the way, you can control autovivification using the [autovivification](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autovivification) pragma.

Answer (score 8):

`Data::Dumper` will tell you the problem here:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my %x;
push @{$x{'12'}}, ();

print Dumper \%x;

my %y;
$y{'12'} = ();

print Dumper \%y;
```

Gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '12' => []
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '12' => undef
        };
```

The two commands aren't equivalent.

Maybe you want:

```
$y{'12'} = [];
```

Instead - `[]` denotes an anonymous array, where `()` denotes an empty list of elements.